# Set the first item's value in DDL (MVC4) to null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DDL in my view and i read items and values of this DDL from DB like this :

```
            ViewBag.ContentGroup = new SelectList(obj.GetContentGrouplist(), "Id", "Name");
```

I put it in **viewbag** and i read the viewbag from the view like this :

```
 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContentGroupFKId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ContentGroupFKId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ContentGroup)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContentGroupFKId)
        </div>
```

So i need a DDL that the first item of that be null how can i do that?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ContentGroupFKId,new SelectList(new List<Object> {new {value = null, text = "Select"} (SelectList)ViewBag.ContentGroup)
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Whatever value you provide is going to be used to generate html in the form of a select list, which doesn't support null. As long as you have a DropDownListFor, it is going to set a value, even if it is empty. The best thing you can do is make the first value a "Please select an item" option and set it to null server side.

There isn't a great way to add the "Please Select" option (at least none that I have seen. People are welcome to correct me though!), but there are a few ways to do it. One would be to create a dummy content group that just has a name and id.

```
var contentGroups = obj.GetContentGrouplist();
contentGroups.Insert(0, new ContentGroup{Id = "0", Name = "Please select a content group"}; 
ViewBag.ContentGroup = new SelectList(contentGroups, "Id", "Name");
```

Or you can create an object (which you would use anywhere you needed this functionality) that just holds a text and value property and then manually add all of your content groups to it, including the empty one.

```
class DropDownListOption{
  public string Text{get;set;}
  public string Value{get;set;}
}
```

then in your code

```
var contentGroups = obj.GetContentGrouplist();
var options = new List<DropDownListOption>();

options.Add(new DropDownListOption{ Id = "0", Text = "Please select a content group"};

foreach(var group in contentGroups)
{
  options.Add(new DropDownListOption{ Id = group.Id, Text = group.Name};
}

ViewBag.ContentGroup = new SelectList(options, "Id", "Name");
```

Both of these options will work. I like the second option better because you can create a generic method of handling all drop down lists a certain way. You will have to handle ContentGroups with an ID of 0 as being null when the user submits the form, but at least it is a way of tracking it.

If I think of another way ill add it.

Comment: So how can i do that ?i mean " "Please select an item"